Solve coupled matrix equations with non-invertible matrices
Assume a set of non-invertible (singular) matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ and the following coupled equations
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &0 = A X+ B Y + C Z\\
    & \lambda Y = A Y+ C X\\ 
    &\lambda Z = A Z+ B X
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $X$, $Y$, and  $Z$ are my variables, also matrices. I can solve this system by isolating $Y$ and $Z$ as $Y=[\lambda  \mathcal{I} - A]^{-1}CX$ and $Z=[\lambda  \mathcal{I} - A]^{-1}BX$ and by plugging it into the equation of $X$, I can solve for $X$, which is what I want.
Interestingly, the solution still holds for $\lambda\rightarrow 0$.
This is a limit which we can only take when the system is solved, if we try to take this limit before isolating the variables, we face that $Y=[\lambda  \mathcal{I} - B]^{-1}X\rightarrow Y=[B]^{-1}X$ and this doesn't exist, because $B$ is non-invertible.

Why does it work?

Why $[\lambda \mathcal{I}-A]^{-1}$ exists while $[A]^{-1}$ doesn't?

I am interested in the this limit $\lambda\rightarrow 0$. It seems that this solution can only be obtained after solving the coupled equations with $\lambda$ and then taking the limit. While this toy model is easy, for a more complex system with many variables, it doesn't seem a viable path. How should one then proceed?



What is $\kappa$ and how do you isolate $Y$ and $Z$?

@obareey ups, it is a typo, it should be $\lambda$. And how to isolate, it is written just below the equation.
